# What constitutes 'encryption' for the purpose of export compliance (e.g. in App Store)?

Tags: ios, encryption, export

When submitting an app to the iOS App Store, one is required to declare whether the app "contains encryption" (and, as I understand, go through additional administrative hurdles).

Does anyone know of any guidance on what precisely is covered by the term "encryption" in this context?

Are they referring to:

- specifically **cryptographically secure** encryption schemes (AES, RSA etc);
- OR, **any** scheme or method that might in everyday parlance be referred to as 'encryption', or a variant of a standard scheme that is cryptographically weak?

Specifically, I was intending to use some weak scheme to protect some of the app's assets against a casual hacker, e.g. by XORing the data from the file with a string of bytes generated from a (non-cryptographic) random number generator. If you like, it would be a "one time pad", but where the key isn't actually cryptographically random: just random enough so that somebody looking to steal the data would need to go to a small amount of effort beyond 'just copying the data out of the file'.

So, for the purposes of the declaration, would this count as using "encryption" even though it's not actually a cryptographically secure form of encryption? What I'm doing is common enough practice that I'm guessing other developers have submitted apps using such a procedure: did you have to declare the app as using encryption?

(The iTunes Connect Guide, for example, doesn't give any further specification on this matter.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This [flow chart](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/forms-documents/encryption/327-flowchart-1/file) will probably help you get on the right track.  It indicates that if the encryption is limited to copyright protection / intellectual property then it is exempt from the review.  I got to this flow chart from the BIS homepage.  That page is referenced by the FAQ entitled *World Wide Trade Compliance for the App Store* in iTunes connect which states you can claim exemption:

> (i) if you determine that your app is not classified under Category 5, Part 2 of the EAR based on the guidance provided by BIS

Hope this helps clear things up a bit.

**EDIT** Another interesting section is this, you can claim exemption if:

> (iii) your app uses, accesses, implements or incorporates encryption with key lengths not exceeding 56 bits symmetric, 512 bits asymmetric and/or 112 bit elliptic curve

Comment: Thanks -- that does answer my question (I assume you meant the FAQ entitled "Could you provide an overview of World Wide Trade Compliance for the App Store?"). I suppose I could then get into an argument as to whether the above scheme constitutes "proprietary functionality", or whether it's close enough to a standard one-time pad to be classed as "previously published". Oh, the riduculousness of it all...

Comment: If it is not published as an approved documented standard, then it is proprietary.  However, you indicate that you use it solely for IP protection (which is exempt according to the BIS guidelines ^^).  Also, if you use strings less than 56 bits in size you should be fine as well :p.  Yes, by the way, I did mean that one.  I realize that you can't link directly to that page...I will make a note in my answer.

Comment: The flow chart link is dead.

Comment: @Boggartfly Looks like they tweaked the link a bit.  I updated it to the new one.